How to prevent Sprite3D from clipping into nearby objects?
Gotot 4.2
Sprite3D is very useful for representing 2D objects within the gameworld. However, when billboarded (Y-billboard), 3D Sprites are prone to clipping into the floor/walls/other 3D models they are close to.

There is an easy way to "force" the sprite3D to be drawn in front of the cube by checking "No depth test" in the sprite 3D's flags, but that makes the sprite visible through all walls/floor.
The other method I tried is to manipulation of the sprite3D's and Cube's material transparency settings:
3D Cube's and Floor's material:
        Transparency: Alpha
        Blend Mode: Mix
        Cull Mode: Disabled
        Depth Draw: Always
        No Depth Test: unticked

This solves the "see-through walls" problem and prevents clipping through the cube, but the sprite3D is still visible through the floor.
Is there some other way to prevent this clipping? Maybe to have the sprite's depth (or "render order") depend on its origin?

I would solve this physics, but you seem to want a purely visual solution.

@Theraot Any solution is welcome. How would physics solve this?

You can do a all or nothing ground test. If sprite.y < ground.y dont draw sprite. Or use a stencil buffer  to mark the type of depth test to use on sprites. How many sprite are you drawing? Personal just move the sprites so they don't intercept existing geometry, or ignore the clipping.

I have no idea how your movement works. For example, how are you preventing the Sprite3D to go through the obstacle? Presumably you can add a radius to that logc.
For example, if you are using a raycast, you can compare the distance of the raycast with a "no clipping radius". Note: this can get complicated quickly, because you might also need to consider if the Sprite3D approaches the obstacle at an angle, and other - literally - edge conditions.
Or if you are using a navigation agent, then the radius of the agent is your "no clipping radius". Note: Of course, this won't work if you don't have a navigation mesh.

The approach I would use would be a physics solution.
To begin with, make sure both ground and the and the obstacle into StaticBody3D or equivalent (you might have already done this).
And then the character would also be a physics body (Probably a CharacterBody3D) with a CollisionShape3D using a sphere shape, and the Sprite3D as children.
The idea of using a sphere is that it looks the same regardless of the angle you look at it, which is also how the billboard effect of the Sprite3D works. You would, of course, make sure the sphere is large enough. So the radius of the sphere is your "no clipping radius".
You would then move the physics object from code, instead of moving the Sprite3D directly. If you move your CharacterBody3D with move_and_slide, it will not go through the object.
Note: a similar solution is possible using RigidBody3D instead of CharacterBody3D, and in that case you would control it with impulses and forces.
